# Quota Exceeded but I only use 1.8 MB

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, quota

Everytime I start up, I get an error message from Ubuntu One that says I've exceeded my quota, but I'm only using 1.8 MB and I thought you got 2 GB.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, with actually (0.0 MB) usage. Later it came to my mind that i had turned off the 'autostart Ubuntu One daemon' at Startup Applications. After re-enabling, it started working normally. You should check if your's running...

[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

You should see something similar (the "Synchronization complete" message is not enough):

[image: Ubuntu One Preferences]

You can check if the daemon is running smoothly with the command `u1sdtool -s`.

I hope this helps.