# Ubuntu One says that my account is full, but it's not

Tags: ubuntu-one

My Ubuntu one is saying that my account is full. It has done that for over a week now, but its the account is not full at all.

I have tried this guide:

1. Quit the Ubuntu One Preferences, if open
2. Open (Lucid): Applications->Accessories->Passwords and Encryption Keys
   (Maverick): System -> Preferences -> Password and Encryption Keys
3. Click on the arrow next to "Passwords"
4. Right-click on the Ubuntu One token and select "Delete"
5. Go to https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/
6. Click on the checkbox next to your computer
7. Click the "Remove selected computers" button
8. (Maverick): killall ubuntu-sso-login; u1sdtool -q; u1sdtool -c
   (Lucid): u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login; u1sdtool -c
9. a web page, if in Lucid, or a window, in Maverick, should open,prompting you to add your computer to your Ubuntu One account
10. Add your computer

This guide did not change any thing and I still get the message that my account is full every time something is syncing.

I've also tried to create and connect to a new account, but the new account was doing the same.

So I am now really confused. Please help!

Comment: Possibly related: [Quota Exceeded but I only use 1.8 MB](http://askubuntu.com/q/29155/6969).

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your UbuntuOne account's disk space is full, and not your local disk space?

Comment: No. There is only 20% in use. That can I see both when I log in on the account on the web and what the ubuntu-one client says. I have 10 gb free on my root-drive. But thanks anyway....